# Como passar para o select option do AJAX para codeigniter view?

Tags: codeigniter-3

Eu pretendo usar uma combobox como filtro de preenchimento de dados para outra combobox código:

**Controller:**

```
function Ajax_consulta_zona()
        {
            $edificio = $this->input->post('edificio');
            $bastidor = $this->input->post('bastidor');

            $resultado = $this->agrupamento->get_zona($edificio, $bastidor);

            echo json_encode($resultado);
        }

        public function get_zona($edificio, $bastidor)
        {
           return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM zona WHERE id_edif = '$edificio' AND id_bast = $bastidor")->result_array();
}
```

**AJAX:**

```javascript
function fill_combo_sala() {

edificio = $('#combo_edificio').val();
    let bastidor = $('#combo_bastidor').val();

    //PATH
    let path = '<?php echo site_url("agrupamento/Ajax_consulta_zona") ?>';

    //Call Ajax
    $.ajax({

        url: path,
        type: 'post',
        data: {"edificio": edificio, "bastidor": bastidor},
        success: function(result){

            let dados = JSON.parse(result);
            console.log(dados);

            $.each(dados, function(id_zona, sala){
                $('#combo_sala').html('');
                $('#combo_sala').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",id_zona).text(sala));
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('Aconteceu um erro de ligação às base de dados');
        }


    });
    }
```

## Valores console.log:

> 0: {id_zona: 1, id_edif: "A01", id_bast: 1, sala: "A", desc_sala: "salaa"}
>   1: {id_zona: 2, id_edif: "A01", id_bast: 1, sala: "B", desc_sala: "salab"}
>   2: {id_zona: 3, id_edif: "A01", id_bast: 1, sala: "C", desc_sala: "salac"}

No campo da combobox aparece `[object Object]`.
O que estarei a fazer mal?

Answer (score 1):

Já consegui resolver.

```js
$.each(dados, function(id, sala){
                
                $('#combo_sala').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",this.sala).text(this.sala));
            });
```